# How to get the values from onlocationchanged to oncreate in android xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on xamarin android app. I am trying to get the latitude, longitude and the cityname in the oncreate method to pass to the service. But I am getting those values only in onlocation change method and not able to get those values in oncreate to pass to service.

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks.

```
 namespace Myapp
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Test")]
        class Test: AppCompatActivity, ILocationListener
        {

            LocationManager locMgr;

            string tag = "Test";

            private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar mToolBar;
            private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
            private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
            private MyAdapter mAdapter;


            public static string latitude = null;
            public static string longitude = null;
            public static string cityname = null;



            protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                SetContentView(Android.Resource.Layout.test);
                mToolBar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Android.Resource.Id.toolbar);
                SetSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
                SupportActionBar.Title = "Test";
                Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Android.Resource.Id.testing);

               mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


                ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progress.Indeterminate = true;
                progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
                progress.SetMessage("Contacting server. Please wait...");
                progress.SetCancelable(false);
                progress.Show();


                locMgr = GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;


                if (locMgr.AllProviders.Contains(LocationManager.NetworkProvider)
                    && locMgr.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider))
                {
                    locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 2000, 1, this);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "The Network Provider does not exist or is not enabled!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }

    **Here I need to pass the latitude, longitude and city name to my service.**       

                  progress.Dismiss();



                    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Count, mRecyclerView, this);
                    //  mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
                    mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
                }



            }


            public async void GetAddress()
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                IList<Address> addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(Convert.ToDouble(latitude), Convert.ToDouble(longitude), 10);

                Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
                if (address != null)
                {
                    StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
                    {
                        deviceAddress.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
                                     .AppendLine(",");
                    }

                    cityname = address.GetAddressLine(1);
                 //   Toast.MakeText(this, address.GetAddressLine(1), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                   // _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address.";

                }
            }


            public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location location)
            {
              //  Log.Debug(tag, "Location changed");
             //   latitude.Text = "Latitude: " + location.Latitude.ToString();
             //   longitude.Text = "Longitude: " + location.Longitude.ToString();
             //   provider.Text = "Provider: " + location.Provider.ToString();


                latitude = location.Latitude.ToString();
                longitude = location.Longitude.ToString();

                GetAddress();

             //   String[] s = cityname.Split(',');



            }
            public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
            {
                Log.Debug(tag, provider + " disabled by user");
            }
            public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
            {
                Log.Debug(tag, provider + " enabled by user");
            }
            public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
            {
                Log.Debug(tag, provider + " availability has changed to " + status.ToString());
            }





        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with desktop programming, on Android you don't get to handle the lifecycle steps of your application. You merely get notified when a change in the lifecycle is taking place and handle it there. In short, the only way to get an up-to-date location is to wait for onLocationChanged to be called.

My suggestion is to either start your service in the onLocationChanged method or start your service, then when onLocationChanged is called, communicate the location to your service. Or your service could be a LocationListener and bypass the communication there.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a link for a simple example I wrote that shows how to make a location request in OnCreate and then get the result in OnLocationChanged. You already have variables for longitude and latitude that are class members. You can set those variables in OnLocationChanged, but the code that does something with those values will need to be called from OnLocationChanged.

https://github.com/LCC-CIT/CS235AM-Demos/tree/master/GeolocationDemo/FusedLoationProvider

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some more description (and sample code) right here, in addition to the link that you have provided.  Links can rot.